# Graphics card(?) causing crashes

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, directx, 3d

I've got a Geforce GTX 660Ti

It's been running fine for 5-6 weeks. Today I launched Left4Dead2 and got 7-8 FPS (usually a rock solid 300 even at the busiest moments).

In case of driver/software issues, I reinstalled Steam, applied all outstanding windows updates, reinstalled the graphics driver (clean install) and finally (after validating local files) reinstalled L4D2.

Now, I've got a slew of problems...

- Launching a 3D app (Anything vaguely modern) causes an immediate crash
- Viewing a site which uses WebGL works fine (http://lights.elliegoulding.com/ works fine)
- GPU-Z works fine (GPU load < 5%)
- Nvidia System monitor crashes after a couple of seconds
- L4D2 crashes immediately
- Tropico 4 crashes immediately
- The longest journey runs fine
- Skype works fine until I turn on my webcam, then crashes immediately
- VLC crashes after 10-20 seconds
- Win7x64 aero glass works fine

Looking at the event viewer, provides a number of problems associated with the crash...

#### Skype

```
Faulting application name: Skype.exe, version: 6.6.0.106, time stamp: 0x51c414b3
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1116
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x00013219
Faulting process id: 0x748
Faulting application start time: 0x01cec5fcd7006ca4
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 73d21ec0-31f3-11e3-abde-1c6f65cec842
```

#### L4D2

```
Faulting application name: left4dead2.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x52262a0b
Faulting module name: tier0.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x52262908
Exception code: 0xc0000417
Fault offset: 0x00022264
Faulting process id: 0x23cc
Faulting application start time: 0x01cec60004dfe146
Faulting application path: D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\Left 4 Dead 2\left4dead2.exe
Faulting module path: D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\Left 4 Dead 2\bin\tier0.dll
Report Id: 475ab7b2-31f3-11e3-abde-1c6f65cec842
```

#### Nvidia Monitor

```
Faulting application name: NVMonitor.exe, version: 6.2.13.1, time stamp: 0x48a9a323
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000200000000
Faulting process id: 0x1200
Faulting application start time: 0x01cec5feb3eb4ce7
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA System Monitor\NVMonitor.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: fbfc9425-31f1-11e3-abde-1c6f65cec842
```

How can I diagnose what is causing the problem? Is it definitely a graphics card problem?

#### GPU-Z

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Is your processor at least a Sandy Bridge? If so, try using its iGPU for video and disconnect your main GPU and see if you're still experiencing the same issues.

Comment: @Basic Are you by chance using an MSI PE card?

Comment: Processor is an i7 2600K. I'll give iGPU as spin as soon as I google it. @Louis It's a Geforce GTX 660Ti - as mentioned in the first sentence.

Comment: @Basic I know, there was a bug with one of MSI's versions of the model.

Comment: @Louis Apologies, my fault for not spotting the thrust of your Q.. It's a [Gigabyte GTX 660Ti OC](http://www.novatech.co.uk/products/components/nvidiageforcegraphicscards/nvidiagtx660tikeplerseries/gv-n66toc-2gd.html). I'll attach a GPU-Z screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So.... Turns out that when developing an app which uses DirectX, I flipped DirectX into debug mode to track down a problem. Debug mode gives detailed information when something goes wrong, but it is extremely slow and many optimizations are disabled.

Since I'd forgotten to swap it back, some apps (OpenGL based) ran perfectly, some ran slowly (L4D2) and some just failed entirely, presumably because they were relying on an implementation detail that was different when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Formatted, reinstalled windows and game from scratch with all newest drivers. Turned out to be the latest version of EVGA precision fan controller.  Reverted back to older version and crashing stopped.

Comment: Interesting gotcha. While it wasn't the one I was hitting, I think it will be useful to others (assuming the symptons were identical).